# Prove the equation combinatorially [full answer provided] - I need explanation for the answer

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

> For every $N ∈ r, n$
>
> $P(n,r) = \sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k}P(n-m,k)P(m,r-k)$
>
> Prove this combinatorially.

**Answer:**

The class has m boys and n - m girls. In what ways can r students be selected for different roles?
On the one hand, the answer is P(n , r) because the order of choice is important and there are no repetitions

On the other hand, all options divide into 1 + r types: choosing k girls and r - k boys,

where  $0\leq $ k $\leq $ r.

Now, choosing k roles for k girls in $\binom{r}{k}$ ways.

And then the roles for the boys are unequivocally determined (the boys will occupy k − r roles remaining).

Now, given in k roles for girls, there are P(n - m, k) options to choose girls with importance for roles. And for k - r roles for boys, there are P(m, r-k) ways choosing options for boys with importance to roles

According to multiplication rule, for k girls there are $\binom{r}{k}P(n-m,k)P(m,r-k)$ ways

According to the addition rule, $\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k}P(n-m,k)P(m,r-k)$

**My question:**

Why all the possibilities fall into r+1 types?

And can someone elaborate the answer in an easy way, or numeric example or different story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can classify the selections according to the number of girls chosen. If we’re choosing $r$ students altogether, there can be any number of girls from $0$ through $r$; that’s one category for each number of girls from $1$ through $r$, plus one extra for no girls at all, for a total of $r+1$ different categories.

Suppose, for instance, that there are $4$ boys, $5$ girls, and we are selecting $3$ students for $3$ different roles. We can choose a group of $3$ students that contains $0$ girls, or $1$ girl, or $2$ girls, or $3$ girls: those are $3+1=4$ different types of group.

Then we count the number of groups of each type. Imagine picking the $3$ students in sequence, so that there is a first student (who gets the first role), a second student (who gets the second role), and a third student (who gets the third role). If for now we look only at the sex of each student, we see that just $\binom30=1$ sequence is possible with with $0$ girls: BBB. There are $\binom31=3$ possible sequences with $1$ girl: BBG, BGB, GBB. There are $\binom32=3$ possible sequences with $2$ girls: BGG, GBG, GGB. And there is $\binom33=1$ possible sequence with $3$ girls: GGG.

When we actually choose specific girls and boys, we have to take into account the individual identities of the students. For instance, there are $4$ boys, so there are $4\cdot3\cdot2=P(4,3)$ ways to choose $3$ of them in a specific order. What about a sequence like BGB? We’re choosing a single girl, which can be done in $5=P(5,1)$ ways, and we’re choosing $2$ boys in a specific order, which can be done in $4\cdot 3=P(4,2)$ ways, so the whole BGB sequence can be chosen in $P(5,1)P(4,2)$ ways. The same goes for the BBG sequence and the GBB sequence, so there are altogether $3P(5,1)P(4,2)$ ways to select a group with $1$ girl.

If we do this for each of the four possible numbers of girls chosen, we find that there are

$$\begin{align*}
&\binom30P(5,0)P(4,3)\text{ groups with }0\text{ girls,}\\
&\binom31P(5,1)P(4,2)\text{ groups with }1\text{ girl,}\\
&\binom32P(5,2)P(4,1)\text{ groups with }2\text{ girls, and}\\
&\binom33P(5,3)P(4,0)\text{ groups with }3\text{ girls.}
\end{align*}$$

In compact form, each line is

$$\binom3kP(5,k)P(4,3-k)\text{ groups with }k\text{ girls}\;,$$

and the total is therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^3\binom3kP(5,k)P(4,3-k)\;.$$

Comment: very nicely explained sir, thank sir!

Comment: when you said 3* P(5,1)P(4,2) why multiplying with 3? I mean P(5,1)P(4,2) isn't enough to calculate the 3 sequences of GBB BGB BBG according to the permutation formula?

Comment: @Mostfashma: No, it’s not enough. $P(5,1)P(4,2)$ is the number of GBB sequences. It’s also the number of BGB sequences. And it’s the number of BBG sequences. Thus, the total number of one-girl sequences is $3P(5,1)P(4,2)$.

Comment: A code have 4 digits in a specific order, the digits are between 0-9, each digit used only once. so there are P(10,4) different ways to do it right? so its sequence for 1234 or 4321 or 5678. that's how i understood it

Comment: @Mostfashma: What you wrote is correct but is not enough to solve the present problem. Here we have $1$ girl in a specific order ($P(5,1)$), $2$ boys in a specific order ($P(4,2)$), and $3$ different ways to combine the two boys with the girls ($\binom31$).